# html pattern="[A-Za-z]{50}" is saying valid input is invalid

Tags: html, regex, input

I have a page with some text fields and I would like to restrict user input, so I have used the html5 pattern attribute, like so:

```
<input name="team_name" type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]{50}" value="<?php echo $team_name;?>">
```

This should allow me to enter only letters b/w Aa-Zz for a name, but when I try to enter a **valid** name, it still tells me to match the requested format.
What am I missing? How come it is always telling me that my input is invalid?

Comment: try `pattern="^[A-Za-z]{1,50}$"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule `[A-Za-z]{50}` will make the name acceptable only when it contains **exact `50` alphabets**.

```
[A-Za-z]{10,50}
```

This will make the name minimum 10 and maximum 50 characters.
Update the expression according to your requirements.

**Demo:**

```css
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="team_name" type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]{10,50}" value="">
  <br />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Validation patterns don't need start and end anchors.

Answer (score 5):

`{50}` in a regex pattern means *exactly* 50 characters. That's unlikely what you want.

If you want to restrict the input to maximum 50 characters, use the `maxlength` attribute.

```
<input name="team_name" type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]+" maxlength="50">
```

Comment: before I had just `pattern="[A-Za-z]"` as an expression and that didn't work either

Comment: I've updated the answer: you'll need to specify that you accept more than one character.

Comment: I was just doing some testing and it accepts quotes both ' and " shouldnt it be catching them as well?

Comment: It doesn't accept them when I try it. And you seem to have accepted another answer that has practically an identical pattern so I guess there's no problem?

Comment: yeah, I don't know what it was, but it got sorted - wanted to accept your answer as well - but yeah - can only accept one :/

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the following :

`type="text"` -> text validation happen.

`pattern="[A-Za-z]{50}"` -> only Aa - Zz alphabets are valid, character inputs are not valid. and string length should be equal to 50.